# Value of the ruble in year 1825

Tags: currency, data-request, russia

Would anyone know how to find out the value of the Russian ruble in the year 1825, in today's (2016) US dollars?

Comment: If you can find data on what the cost of living was like in Russia in 1825, then you could compare the costs from back then and today, but such a task would be monumentally difficult if such data didn't currently exist already.

Comment: [This](http://www.iisg.nl/hpw/data.php#russia) might help

Answer (score 1):

[This website](http://opoccuu.com/kurs.htm) (in Russian) states that, in 1825,
you could sell 1 [Imperial Ruble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruble#Imperial_ruble_.2814th_century_.E2.80.93_1917.29) and get 0.72 US dollars. I don't know Russian so I cannot tell the source of that data.

Those 0.72 US dollars in 1825 are worth US$15.49 in 2016, according to [this website](https://westegg.com/inflation/).

Therefore, **1 Imperial Ruble of 1825 was equivalent to US$15.59 in 2016.**

Additionally, [this website](http://www.iisg.nl/hpw/data.php#russia) has information of prices of different goods and wages for Russia since the 16th century.